# Why does accepting answers not automatically upvote them?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

I've seen this a lot on my own answers, where they have been accepted but received 0 upvotes. Is there a reason why this is possible, and not just automatically upvoted on accept? On the other hand, is there a good reason to not upvote an accepted answer?

Here is some examples:

- User who does not have 15 rep (no upvote privileges) https://stackoverflow.com/a/74445136/10630900
- User with clearly enough rep (thus can upvote, so why not?) https://stackoverflow.com/a/73340105/10630900

To me anyway, I thought accepting an answer implies it's the most useful, since it indicates it helped you solve your problem. Thus, I would expect that accepted answers would also be upvoted to indicate they are useful to that person.

Comment: This change could be considered, but then accepting shouldn't provide 15 rep points anymore. Either the additional points are lowered or removed.

Comment: Is it possible for an answer to both solve a problem, but also be of not the best quality? I don't think "Try this:" answers that happen to guess correctly should just automatically receive upvotes because they're correct. The OP is one person, ultimately the value from voting comes from the people helped in the future. The op is at most worth 25 rep, where as helping future visitors, the goal of the site, can award you thousands.

Comment: @Minn I'm going to flip that on you. Why do you not upvote every question that you answer? Not all questions are clear and useful enough to get an upvote, even if they are answerable. Not all answers are clear and useful enough to get an upvote, even if they seem to work for the OP at the time.

Comment: because people want the unsung hero badge :)

Answer (score 3):

Technically, this is a reasonable request — accepting an answer kind of implies *you* found it useful (whatever the definition "useful" you have). However, up and downvotes are supposed to indicate that a post is useful not only to *you*, but in general (or, in other words, for *others* as well), so it makes sense that accepting an answer and voting on it are not tied together (it is not beyond reason that one finds a post useful to *them*, but not to *others*).

Given the above, I am not sure the request is a useful way of spending the quite limited developer time, and more of a request for a community-made userscript. As a matter of fact, I've just [written one](https://stackapps.com/q/9607) that should automatically upvote an answer upon accepting it (more conditions are to be added later).